# Put $promise data in a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, promise, angular-promise

I'm getting data back from a resource like this:

```
var result = someService.getData();
result.$promise.then(function() {
    console.log(result);
});
```

This gives me the following result:

```
1: "200"
2: "1810"
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
__proto__: f
```

I need to put this data in a javascript array, that looks like this:

```
[[1, 200], [2, 1810]]
```

I tried to do this in a `forEach`:

```
var data = [];
angular.forEach(monthly, function(value, key) {
    var tmp = [];
    tmp[0] = key;
    tmp[1] = value;

    data.push(tmp);
});
```

But then the `$promise` and `$resolved` properties are also appearing in the foreach. This also doesn't look like the best way to do it either.

How should I do this in a proper way?

Comment: Have you tried passing your callback function directly to `someService.getData()` ?

Comment: @aduch Not sure what you mean? I call `someService.getData()` inside my controller` And `getData()` uses a `$resource` to make a call to a web service. A `$resource` always returns a `$promise`, so that's what `getData()` returns. What do I have to change according to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is call `.toJSON()` - doing so will strip the $promise and $resolved properties off and allow you to use `angular.forEach` on it properly like you could in older versions of Angular.

Something like:

```
var result = someService.getData();
result.$promise.then(function(value) {
    console.log(value.toJSON());//will strip the annoying properties, use here
});
```

Comment: Ok, good to know that the "auto - unwrapping" like I use now is deprecated. But your method still gives me an object which has the properties `$promise` and `$resolved`. So I'm still stuck with the original problem.

Comment: @Vivendi before I add clarification to the answer I want to be sure - what browsers do you have to support? Also can I assume $resource?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It is quite obvious that OP is using `$resource`, so there is no auto-unwrapping. Your statement is misleading, because `$resource`'s immediately returning an empty array (or object) is **not** deprecated (unless I've missed something).

Comment: @ExpertSystem I'll investigate it further, although it appears to still be there in there in the source code I clearly remember reading about it being removed in $resource (and not just promises) - I admit that in second thought this might have been in a "somewhat internal" google doc with plans for 1.3 - this might have not ended up in 1.3 after all (as with other stuff from there) and I might be wrong here so take what I wrote with two grains of salt - I'll go ask around and make sure.

Comment: I'll remove that part in the interim.

Comment: @Vivendi make sure you are using `angular.toJson()` ... Also, note that the behavior of this function changes from [Angular 1.2](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) to [Angular 1.3](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.19/docs/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) ... Click those links to the docs for details. I haven't paid much attention to 1.3 yet, but in 1.3 it only strips properties beginning with "$$". Can anyone confirm are all Angular's private properties prefixed with $$ in 1.3?

Comment: @SunilD. in 1.3 it explicitly removes `$resolved` and `$promise`. It no longer relies on `$$` and properties in the resource may start with $. You can see the relevant commit in the changelog.

Comment: For anyone wondering, Benjamin is referring to **[this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d3c50c845671f0f8bcc3f7842df9e2fb1d1b1c40)**, referenced in the changelog **[here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-features-10)**.

Comment: @ExpertSystem you appear to be correct about automatic unwrapping `$resource`, I have talked to an involved party and the plans to disable auto-unwrapping ngResource were quickly aborted because it made people angry and they complained this wasn't magic because it was a resource explicitly and not an arbitrary promise. I apologize for the disinformation - thanks for the catch.